# ASP.NET and sending SMS/making phone calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms

I have a scenario where I need to make a call to a telephone(landline/mobile)  or send SMS to a particular set of users only using ASP.NET and C#. The web application is not a mobile application.

How do I go about doing these? What typically would be the hardware requirements? I would be **extremely grateful** if you could provide me with pointers and reference websites.

Comment: I should have been more specific stating that I require it in India.

Answer (score 2):

Most carriers provide an email address that you can send text messages to — for example, with Verizon, you can send an email to *phonenumber@vtext.com* and it will show up as a text message to that number.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway#Carrier-provided_Email_or_Web_to_SMS_gateways) has a full list of the carrier-provided email addresses.

By sending text messages as "emails" you can take advantage of [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're looking for hardware solutions to automate yourself, or external services. However, I've used BT's [Web21C](http://web21c.bt.com/) pretty extensively.

They have an excellent .Net API and a host of functionality. Their pricing is the best in the UK, but might fall down with US SMS, which is obviously cheaper - there are plenty of other SMS API providers though.

What BT do offer, which is rare, is an API interface for automating call dialling, conferencing and managing call flow.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "make a call"?  Do you just need to call someone to transfer them or make your own custom, interactive automated call?

If you just need to make a simple call to transfer someone, there are services like [VoiceStar](http://www.voicestar.com) that can do this.  If you need to make a custom automated call, I would suggest [OCS 2007 Speech Server](http://www.microsoft.com/uc/products/speechserver.mspx).  Asterisk is a SIP PBX and may or may not work for you depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

As far as sending text messages, I don't have much experience so others answers would probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com). You can find the [.NET/C# helper library on GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp).

Answer (score 0):

Via [WebServiceX](http://www.webservicex.net/WCF/ServiceDetails.aspx?SID=20), you can send SMS messages anywhere in the world.  For phone calls I'd use [Asterisk](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/AsteriskIAXClientWrapper.aspx).

Comment: WebServiceX does not cover all service providers in India

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a UK then [Esendex](http://www.esendex.com/en/Developers/SDKs/NET-SMS-SDK/) provides a nice WebService although BT's Web21C does seem to be that little bit cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

[messagepub](http://messagepub.com), provides a single interface API to send not just SMS and make phone calls, but also IM, Twitter, and email messages. It might help you solve your problem.

They have a C# helper library that you could use to easily integrate multichannel messaging into your application.

Comment: Message Pub appears to be out of business.

Answer (score 0):

For Turkish developers: http://www.mutlusms.com/yazilimgelistiriciler.html

Answer (score 0):

I had built one a while back using an SMS gateway server. This was done in .net 1.1,ASP.net & vb.net. If i remember correctly, i built up a simple webpage and posted my request to the sms gateway server via http post.

The webpage carried a simple textbox and a button to submit. Once that was done, posted the message. The packet included username & password for authentication & an sms message.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about calls but a very good API is available for free in Pakistan for [sending and receiving sms](http://www.sendsms.pk) easily. I gave it a try and my application is working great!